# What’s the standard way to gloss a morpheme that provides subject, object and tense?

Tags: morphology, tense, interlinear-gloss, morphological-analysis

If there a Leipzig standard to gloss a suffix like

“1st person subject, second person object, past tense”

My best guess is

> 1.S.2.O.Past

And then what if it’s first person exclusive

> 1.EXCL.S.2.O.Past

This looks really clunky, but maybe it’s proper.

I didn’t see anything in the Leipzig standards on this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Those glosses are what I'd expect to see glossed, though that's a lot of grammatical content for one morpheme!

Comment: Wouldn't it usually be 1S.2O.Past and 1exclS.2O.Past?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut I guess you’d want a period between excl and S, no? After all, S and excl will be listed separately on the list of glosses at the end